# Dropping a hierarchical linear model intercept when centering the outcome at 0?

Tags: regression-coefficients, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, scales, centering

Suppose a hierarchical linear model with "random intercepts" $\mu_i$ fit to some raw (unscaled) data:

$$y_i \sim N(\mu_0 + \mu_i, \sigma) \\
\mu_i \sim N(0,\sigma)$$

If I rescale $y_i$ by subtracting the sample mean of $y$ from $y_i$, I know that $\mu_0 = 0$.

1. Is there any reason I shouldn't drop $\mu_0$ from the model after de-meaning $y_i$ since the value of $\mu_0$ is known? I ask since I'm trying to understand whether it is possible to set the location of $\mu_i$ without explicitly including a $\mu_0$ in the model.
2. If I don't drop $\mu_0$ and make Bayesian inferences, I need a prior on $\mu_0$. While it should be centered at 0, should the variance be almost 0 since we know $\mu_0 = 0$ in sample, provided that we expect the sample mean to be close to the population mean?

Comment: Your language is ambiguous and puzzling: by "its mean," one would understand the expectation of $y_i,$ which you stipulate is the *unknown* value $\mu_0+\mu_i.$  (If it's known, why are you fitting anything?)  So, how do you propose to subtract an unknown quantity from $y_i$?

Comment: By "rescale $y_i$ to have mean 0 by subtracting its mean" I mean subtracting the sample mean of $y$ from $y_i$.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your tags so you include multilevel-analysis as one of the options.

Comment: Will update to be more specific when I get a chance tonight. For now added the tag. The context I'm considering is whether it makes sense to subtract the sample mean from y then drop $\mu_0$ since identifying the random intercept model requires fixing the mean of the intercepts at some value. Could then allow the hierarchical mean to vary.

Comment: Re the edit: even upon subtracting the *sample* mean from the data, it does not follow that $\mu_0=0.$  You are merely *estimating* $\mu_0$ using the sample mean.  Unless your data are well balanced, that might be a relatively poor estimator and you won't have an accurate standard error for it, either.

Answer (score 2):

In brief, no, you should not drop $\mu_0$ from the model (even if you've mean-centered).  The main reason that comes to mind is that the estimation process is still estimating a grand mean along with all the other parameters.  And if you drop the grand mean from the model, you free up one more degree of freedom that probably should not be free.

If you mean center your overall sample, then you've introduced an additional source of sampling error into the estimated group means (as it is unlikely your sample grand mean is the same as the population grand mean).  And this is why it is best to leave the degrees of freedom for the model at their correct values.

Another way to think about this is that your statement about $\mu_0=0$ is incorrect.  You don't now what the population grand mean is, you only know that it will estimate to zero:  $\hat{\mu}_0=0$.

As for your second query, I personally would use a uniform prior or a normal distribution (relying on the prior you have for the variance).  However, as with any prior, this really depends on the context and the justification for your beliefs about that parameter.

Comment: While it's true that sampling error is added, I'm in particular considering a context where a model is not identified without a parameter fixed to a constant (usually 0 to ensure mean of errors is 0).

Comment: To clarify, ¿are you assuming that $\mu_0=0$ for the grand mean for the entire population?

Comment: Yes - this is what I mean by "fixing" it.